# Font Embedding for Editable PDFs

Tags: pdf, fonts, acrobat, truetype, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to figure out a way to successfully embed full fonts (not just the subset) within an editable PDF to create a PDF that allows the end-user to customize the information within each of the editable fields without losing the font styling and without having to separately download the font themselves. Some fonts will allow it, while others that are downloaded/purchased will not. However, I have seen others do this successfully and I know that the particular font that I am working with was purchased with a license for commercial use so there should not be any permission issues with embedding it. I have also seen this particular font in use for editable PDFs. I am working on Illustrator CC and Adobe Pro DC. I've used the Preflight Embed Missing Fonts option to no avail, as well as changing the Illustrator Setting for substituting fonts to 0% and neither has worked successfully. Any suggestions? Is this an additional plug in?

Comment: Just because others do it doesn't mean it's legal. If the font you buy does not have the OpenType [`fsType`](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/OTSpec/os2.htm#fst) value set to allow full embedding (values 0 or 8, or 4 for read-only documents), then you don't get to embed them. Can you change that value yourself? Sure. Is that legal? Not in the slightest. Can you do it for your-use or research-purposes only? Of course. Are you going to give these PDF to *anyone* else? Like, anyone at all, doesn't matter who? Then you probably shouldn't be handing over evidence that you've broken the law.

Comment: If with "editable" you mean for use in a form field, you simply assign that font to the field. If it is not fully embeddable, you will get a message. Otherwise, it will be fully embedded. If your font is not fully embeddable, contact the vendor of the font for a fully embeddable version. If they refuse, find another font vendor.